# Arcpy SelectLayerByLocation giving an error

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

this script is supposed to select features within distance in two layers based on some their characteristics one feature will get a score (example: water pipes crossing naturally sensitive areas like rivers, the type of that river and its permanency matter in the scoring, so each type will be selected then used in select by lactation function to give water pipes that are within a distance its score

this is the error I get when i run these codes:

Executing: SelectLayerByLocation water_mains WITHIN_A_DISTANCE Just_selected "2.5 Meters" NEW_SELECTION
Start Time: Thu Sep 25 15:21:09 2014
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
A column was specified that does not exist.
A column was specified that does not exist.
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation).

the select layer by location is in a script that is called by another script (main script)

the main script :

```
def main():

    try:

        import arcpy
        from arcpy import env
        # pathing to avoid retyping 
        env.workspace = "C:/Users/abusheikan/Desktop/prev_files/RiskAnalysisModel"
        dataPath = 'C:\\Users\\abusheikan\\Desktop\\prev_files\\RiskAnalysisModel\\ToolData2'

        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

        import imp

        ##Defines INPUT variables
        #some variable wont be used but are there for future use, I'm starting off as simple as possible
        creekLayer = dataPath + "\\ENVIRONMENTAL\\OHN_WaterCourse.shp"
        PipeLayer=dataPath + "\\SERVICES\\water_mains.shp"

        nameField = 'ROW_1'
        scoreField = 'ROW_SCORE1'
        crossingField = 'CROSS_ROW1'
        ROWfield = 'ROW_TRUE1'

        diaField='INTERNAL_D'
        rangeVal= 416

        Field = 'WARTERCOURS'
        Field2='PERMANENCY'

        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(PipeLayer,"water_mains")
        inFeatures = "water_mains"

        #The following lists contain road classes. Format is (a, b, c,d) such that a is the creek class name,
        #b is an average permencnacy of flow, c is the width, nd d is the xscore to be given .
        #Lower value of c means lower criticality.

        creeks = [('Vertual Flow','intermittent',10,1),
                  ('Vertual Connector','intermittent', 10,2),
                  ('Vertual Flow','Permanent', 10,1),
                  ('Vertual Connector', 'Permanent', 10,2),
                  ('Ditch','Intermittent',5,3),
                  ('Ditch','Permanent',5,4),
                  ('Stream','Intermittent',5,3),
                  ('Stream','Intermittent',5,4)]
       ## the following isnt used yet
        creeks2 = [('Vertual Flow','intermittent',10,1),
                  ('Vertual Connector','intermittent', 10,2),
                  ('Vertual Flow','Permanent', 10,1),
                  ('Vertual Connector', 'Permanent', 10,2),
                  ('Ditch','Intermittent',5,3),
                  ('Ditch','Permanent',5,4),
                  ('Stream','Intermittent',5,3),
                  ('Stream','Intermittent',5,4)]        


  ## This codeblock isnt utilized yet and will always return row_score, it is supposed to adjusts the value of ROW_SCORE
  ##based on whether the water main crosses a creek, by looking up the value in CROSS_ROW1 feild that is obtained later on 
        expression = "crossing(!CROSS_ROW1!,!ROW_SCORE1!)"

        codeblock = """def crossing(crosses, row_score):
            if crosses != 0:
                return 5
            else:
                return row_score"""



    except:
        arcpy.AddError("Definitions failed")
        arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())

    try:
        ## pathing to a funtion to be called
        fpath = 'C:\\Users\\abusheikan\\Desktop\\prev_files\\RiskAnalysisModel\\Scripts\\'
        ## defining the function pathing we retyped anyway for debugging purpuses.
        functions = imp.load_source('functions', 'C:\\Users\\abusheikan\\Desktop\\prev_files\\RiskAnalysisModel\\Scripts\\functions_creeks.py')
         ## check check :-p
        arcpy.AddMessage("Funtions Loaded")

    except:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Functions not loaded")

    try:


    ##Clear all selections, because otherwise commands will be applied only to selected features, why? I ont know pls explain where this is
        ## supposed to be used and where not to. THANKs!

        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inFeatures, "CLEAR_SELECTION")
        arcpy.AddMessage("Selected")

    ##This new field will show the road overlying the pipe. Default value of "no Creek" will be assigned.
        arcpy.AddField_management(inFeatures, nameField, "TEXT")

        arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeatures, nameField, '"No Creek"')

    ##This field will contain a score for the highest creek class over the pipe.
    ##  Default of 0 means no creeks 
        arcpy.AddField_management(inFeatures, scoreField, "SHORT")

        arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeatures, scoreField, 1)

        arcpy.AddField_management(inFeatures, crossingField, "SHORT")


##        arcpy.AddField_management(mainRoadLayer, ROWfield, "FLOAT",3,1)
##        arcpy.CalculateField_management("t_Pavement_Line", ROWfield, expressionROW, "PYTHON_9.3", codeblockROW)

    except:

        #Report error
        arcpy.AddError("Could not create new fields")

        #Report error messages
        arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())

    try:

##        functions.roadclass_loop is a function that loops through all creek classes in
##        a list, selects the water mains within a distance of each one, and assigns the
##        appropriate score. Full script is in the called function.


## the following s a failed test so never mind that commented out line, it may ciome in handy so left it in there
       ## arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(PipeLayer, 
           ## "JUST_MADE",str(dialField) + " <= "+ str(rangeVal)) 


         ## calls creek_loop funtion() i think here is where the error is created pls check the inputs they may be where problem is! but i cant see anything wrong with them.
        functions.roadclass_loop(creeks, creekLayer, Field, inFeatures, "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE",
                                                 nameField, scoreField)
        arcpy.AddMessage("small pipes")            

        ## same as b4 but with the second tuple list.       
        functions.roadclass_loop(creeks2, creekLayer, Field, inFeatures, "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE",
                                 nameField, scoreField)
        arcpy.AddMessage("BIG PIPES")


       ## functions.roadclass_loop(provincial, provincialLayer, Field3, inFeatures, "INTERSECT",
       ##                          "", crossingField)

##        If the CROSS_ROW field has a nonzero value (i.e. if the water main crosses a large road)
##        the road class score will be increased to 5(the maximum). 
        ## inserts the scores into the 
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(inFeatures, scoreField, expression, "PYTHON_9.3", codeblock)

    except:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Could not run")
        arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())


if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

the called function is:

```
def test():
##    import arcpy
    arcpy.AddMessage("This function works")

##def roadclass_loop(listOfClassTuples, sourceLayer, fieldName, targetLayer,
##                   outputField1, outputField2):

def roadclass_loop(listOfClassTuples, sourceLayer, fieldName, targetLayer, crossingType,
                   outputField1, outputField2):

    import arcpy
    from arcpy import env

    env.workspace = "C:/data/"

    ##try: 

    for creekclass in listOfClassTuples:

            (classname, Permanency, creekWidth, score) = creekclass

            bufferDistance = creekWidth*0.5
    try:
            if crossingType == "INTERSECT":
                stringBuffer = ""
            else: 
                stringBuffer = "%s Meters" % str(bufferDistance)
    except:
            arcpy.AddMessage("its here")
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(sourceLayer, "Just_selected",
                                      fieldName + "= '"+ classname + "'")
    #arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Just_Selected", "JUST_SELECTED", FieldName2+" = '"+ Permanency + "'") 

    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(targetLayer, crossingType,
                                           "Just_selected", stringBuffer, "NEW_SELECTION")

    classname = classname.lower()

    if outputField1!= "":                                        

                arcpy.CalculateField_management(targetLayer, outputField1,   classname )

                arcpy.CalculateField_management(targetLayer, outputField2,   score )


    arcpy.Delete_management("Just_selected")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(targetLayer, "CLEAR_SELECTION")

    ##except:

       # arcpy.AddMessage("Function failed")
        #arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

Answer (score 2):

See this question on the GIS StackExchange: [Points in Polygon Count: Error with arcpy.selectLayerByLocation_management](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52141/points-in-polygon-count-error-with-arcpy-selectlayerbylocation-management) . They made a mistake when calling MakeFeatureLayer_management, but the error was thrown by SelectLayerByLocation_management. You may have a similar situation.

In your case, are you confident that the feature class stored in `dataPath + "\\ENVIRONMENTAL\\OHN_WaterCourse.shp"` has a field called `WARTERCOURS`? Is there maybe a typo there? (The word `WARTERCOURS` caught my attention; [Google says](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%2BWARTERCOURS) you're the first person on the Internet to use it.)

Comment: Sir, you've got a keen eye for details. indeed it was a typo. but now I get the could not run message meaning the second code could not be run although successfully called. I'll have a look at the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is your listOfClassTuples, which is being fed by your creeks variable, supposed to be set of fields within your creekLayer (dataPath + "\ENVIRONMENTAL\OHN_WaterCourse.shp)?

Comment: yes, the first two columns of creeks (type and permanency), are indeed information obtained form the creek layer, however the width and score are obtained for each row within creek layer by matching the first two